# How to get characters from a text like LEFT() but using google apps script

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script

I need to separate characters from 1 text. It is very easy using the Left() and right() formulas of Google Sheets, but replace it with Google Apps Script I don't know which function.

```
ADGGGGGDH--12/01

VNS-VNSBCAAAMVNC--02/07
```

I need to separate the last 7 characters from the string, and this is what i want `ADGGGGGDH` and `VNS-VNSBCAAAMVNC`.
Thanks for the solution

Comment: how about "VNS-VNSBCAAAMVNC--02/07".splice(-7) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice